# Flutter: Async issues with third party login

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter

I'm trying to implement native facebook login in Flutter.

So far I have a MethodChannel:

```
const platform = const MethodChannel('com.app/facebook');
```

I have a button in flutter that launches into the login sequence:

```
onPressed: () async {
  try {
    final String fbButtonResult = await platform.invokeMethod('doFacebookLogin');
    fbLoginResult = 'FB Button Result: $fbButtonResult';
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    fbLoginResult = "No FB button: '${e.message}'";
  }
  print("this never executes");
  print(fbLoginResult);
}
```

And I have some iOS code to execute the native login:

```
FlutterViewController* controller = (FlutterViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;

FlutterMethodChannel* facebookChannel = [FlutterMethodChannel
                                        methodChannelWithName:@"com.app/facebook"
                                        binaryMessenger:controller];

[facebookChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall* call, FlutterResult result) {
    // check which function was called
    if ([@"doFacebookLogin" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login
         logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email"]
         fromViewController:controller
         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *fbResult, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
                 result(@"Process error");
             } else if (fbResult.isCancelled) {
                 NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                 result(@"Cancelled");
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Logged in");
                 result(@"Logged in");
             }
         }];
    } else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
    }
}];
```

When we execute this, the FB native login functionality works great and runs through the flow properly. When it is done, the NSLog for "Logged In" shows up in the log, but the result doesn't seem to ever get back to the flutter app to let me know there what happened.

We need to know in some way whether this was successful or not so we can get the credentials and advance the view to the next step. Is there an issue in the code above or do I misunderstand how MethodChannels work? Or do we need to do something completely different like do an invokeMethod from the iOS code back to flutter once the flow is finished? Or is there some simple way to know when focus has returned to my flutter widget so I can check to see if the login was successful or not?

Comment: Hey, I tried your code, but instead of calling FB, I used dummy work:  `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        result(@"hello from ios!");
      });` It works well. Can you try without FB? Does it work?

Comment: So, I restarted everything and cycled through some other iOS simulators and this code worked. Super-frustrating. Thanks to @Mogol and anyone else who played around with this.